# How to move files from one path to another

Tags: linux

need to move files from source path"u01/app/java/gids4/textfiles/output/foursight/request" to destination path " /u01/app/java/gids4/textfiles/output/archive/foursight/request"

Comment: use `mv` command

Answer (score 1):

If you want move files and you have set path, you can simply use `mv` command, where you use this path in argument.

```
path="/home/user"
mv $path"/some/folder/*" $path"/another/folder/*"
```

Answer (score 1):

If these paths are directories, do

```
mv /u01/app/java/gids4/textfiles/output/foursight/request/* /u01/app/java/gids4/textfiles/output/archive/foursight/request/
```